# Gensim Doc2Vec: Less vectors generated than expected

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gensim, doc2vec

I am building a program that assigns multiple labels/tags to textual descriptions. I am using Gensim's Doc2Vec to vectorize each of the text descriptions. However, when I print out the length of the Doc2Vec's model's vectors, it returns the number of different tags there are, not the number of descriptions. In other words, it returns vectors representing the tags, not the documents. This inevitable leads to a ValueError when I try splitting the data (using sklearn):

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [64, 8370]

Below is my code:

```
textList = []

for i in range(0, len(unformattedText)):
    text = unformattedText[i]
    tag = tagList[i]
    textList.append(TaggedDocument(words=text.split(" "), tags=[tag]))

numCores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() 
model = Doc2Vec(textList, workers=numCores, vector_size=100)

docVectors = []
for j in range(0, len(model.docvecs)):
    docVectors.append(model.docvecs[j])
x = docVectors

vectorizer2 = MultiLabelBinarizer()
vectorizer2.fit(tagList)
y = vectorizer2.transform(tagList)

xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20)
```

Variable dimensions: `x` is an array of length 64 and `y.shape = (8370, 24)`

Comment: What is `unformattedText`? What is `len(unformattedText)`? What is `len(set(tagList))`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what the `tags` field represents, as you seem to imply that some of your documents share tags, but you want one vector per document. Tags are mostly used to index documents, and it is recommended that each document have its unique tag ID.

From the documentation:

> Tags may be one or more unicode string tokens, but **typical practice** (which will also be the most memory-efficient) **is for the tags list to include a unique integer id as the only tag**.

This is because doc2vec learns one vector per *tag*, and the typical use case of doc2vec necessitates one vector per *document*. Two documents that share tags will effectively be treated as one document split in two by the algorithm.

In your case, you can use `i` as the document tag, or get more sophisticated if your text list grows too large to hold in memory at once in order to easily retrieve the relevant file from the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Doc2Vec` learns vectors for each `tag` you supply. If you need to one unique vector per document, then you should give each document a unique ID tag.

On the other hand, if you have 1000 documents, but they re-use only 100 tags, `Doc2Vec` only learns 100 tag-vectors. Essentially, all the texts that were submitted with the same tag were considered a single, combined virtual document, even though they were passed-in separately.

(You *could* do your training with such coalesced documents, but then afterwards use `infer_vector()` to infer new unique vectors for each text, rather than looking up the vectors learned during bulk training.)

Separately, note that most published `Doc2Vec` work uses 10 training epochs or more. And, especially with smaller corpuses (in document count or typical size of texts), more `epochs` would be helpful. But your manner of invoking `Doc2Vec` will use its default `epochs=5` (inherited from shared code with `Word2Vec`).